# How to update a pattern in a column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace

I have a table `A (CODE, TEXT)`

I ran the following query

```
select * from A
```

I see that column `TEXT` has values with trailing 15 commas

Is it possible to remove these trailing commas by a query?

Comment: What is type of TEXT column in your case is it ntext?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're really just looking for hard-code "15 commas" to end a field, you could just chop off the last 15 characters of Text:

```
UPDATE A
    SET Text = SUBSTRING(Text, 1, LEN(Text)-15)
    WHERE Text LIKE '%,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,'
```

Or you could just replace 15 commas anywhere with empty space anywhere in the Text

```
UPDATE A
    SET Text = REPLACE(Text, ',,,,,,,,,,,,,,,', '')
    WHERE Text LIKE '%,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,'
```

Answer (score 0):

In case your TEXT column is of type **VarChar** use

```
UPDATE A
SET Text = REPLACE(Text, ',,,,,,,,,,,,,,,', '')
WHERE Text LIKE '%,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,'
```

In case your TEXT column is of type **ntext** use

```
UPDATE A
SET TEXT = CAST(REPLACE(CAST(TEXT as NVarchar(MAX)),',,,,,,,,,,,,,,,','') AS NText)
WHERE Text LIKE '%,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,'
```

In this case you can not replace directly because if you try to replace it directly it will break with error 'Argument data type ntext is invalid for argument 1 of replace function'